# Neo4j: How do I delete a specific relationship with cypher?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Lets say, I have an user:

```
CREATE (n { name: 'Tamil' })
```

and 2 roles:

```
CREATE (n { name: 'developer' } ) 
CREATE (n { name: 'tester' } )
```

Then, I make relationship between the user & each of the 2 roles.

```
CYPHER 1.9  START a = node(*), b = node(*) 
WHERE a.name = 'Tamil' AND b.name = 'developer' 
CREATE (a)-[r:HAS_ROLE]->(b) 
RETURN r

CYPHER 1.9  START a = node(*), b = node(*) 
WHERE a.name = 'Tamil' AND b.name = 'tester' 
CREATE (a)-[r:HAS_ROLE]->(b) 
RETURN r
```

Now, I want to remove tester role relationship from the user.
I tried:

```
CYPHER 1.9  START a = node:node_auto_index('name:Tamil') 
MATCH a-[r:HAS_ROLE]-() 
RETURN r
```

But, it returns both of the relationships. 
I know that i can attach property with relationships. But, again, I don't know the cypher syntax for that.

I am new to Neo4j. Any suggestions would be really great!

Thanks!

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I deleted the relationship on your original graph with this query:

```
START n=node(*) 
MATCH (n)-[rel:HAS_ROLE]->(r) 
WHERE n.name='Tamil' AND r.name='tester' 
DELETE rel
```

Comment: With version 3.0.3, you have to change the MATCH clause to MATCH (n)-[rel:HAS_ROLE]->(r ) or you get an error (note the parentheses around the 'n' and 'r')

Comment: Is it the same syntax 2019?

Answer (score 1):

I found it. I changed the relationships to have property. Like this:

```
CYPHER 1.9  START a = node(*), b = node(*) 
WHERE a.name = 'Tamil' AND b.name = 'developer' 
CREATE (a)-[r:HAS_ROLE {id: xyz}]->(b) 
RETURN r

CYPHER 1.9  START a = node(*), b = node(*) 
WHERE a.name = 'Tamil' AND b.name = 'tester' 
CREATE (a)-[r:HAS_ROLE {id: abc}]->(b) 
RETURN r
```

Then this below code deleted the specified relationship.

```
CYPHER 1.9  START a = node:node_auto_index('name:Tamil') 
MATCH a-[r:HAS_ROLE]-() 
WHERE r.id = abc
DELETE r;
```

I am not sure that this is the right way to do or not. But, it works.

Comment: This seems really counterintuitive - how will you know what the relationship's ID is? Take a look at Werner's answer, which should work for you.